# C# split first two in string, then keep all the rest together

Tags: c#

Okay, the question could probably a phrased better.  I have a string.

```
2008 apple micro pc computer
```

i want the string split by `' '` for the first 2 delimiters and then keep the rest together. so it'll return

```
2008  
apple  
micro pc computer
```

This is a made up string so it could be anything, but it's still first 2 split, then all the rest no matter how much is all the rest

Another example

```
 apple orange this is the rest of my string and its so long
```

returns

```
apple  
orange  
this is the rest of my string and its so long
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Pass a second argument to specify how many items at max to split into. In your case, you'd pass 3 so you have the first two parts split by space, and the rest of the string in the third.

```
string myString = "2008 apple micro pc computer";
string[] parts = myString.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
string s = "this is a test for something";            
string[] string_array =  s.Split(' ');
int length = string_array.Length;
string first = string_array[0];
string second = string_array[1];
string rest = "";
for (int i = 2; i < length; i++) rest = rest + string_array[i] + " ";
rest.TrimEnd();
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You can use `string.LastIIndexof` for the rest of the words after implementing point 2 i.e after append the first two words.
2. Split it using `string.split` and fetch first two
3. Finally append the result of Point and Point 2